# net-snmp: how do I register for a new enterprise trap?

Tags: c, snmp, net-snmp, snmp-trap

I'm working with net-snmp and agentx.  I have to register my enterprise OIDs for scalars and tables.  For example:

```
netsnmp_register_read_only_scalar(...); // register my scalars
netsnmp_tdata_register(...); // register my table
```

Until I make those calls in my agentx code, my OIDs don't show up in snmpd.

My MIB file also has NOTIFICATION-TYPE definitions, such as:

```
myTrapTest NOTIFICATION-TYPE
    STATUS          current
    DESCRIPTION     "A sample trap."
    ::= { myNotifications 1 }
```

I took a look at `#include <net-snmp/agent/agent_trap.h>` but this file seems to be about sending traps, not registering custom ones.

***My question:***  What do I call to register my trap definitions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there is no registration required for traps.  When I asked on the NET-SNMP mailing list, the answer I received was:

> You need to 'register' variables/tables so that the master
>   agent knows which sub-agent to call/invoke (you versus the other guy)
>   when a particular OID is get/set, but...
>
> You don't have to 'register' trap definitions, you simply have to
>   'send' the (correctly composed) notification (agentx-Notify-PDU).

(Source:  http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.network.net-snmp.user/35320 )

Comment: I understand that the answer is probably outdated, but have you managed to create application-specific traps? I've got a slightly similar problem described [here](http://superuser.com/questions/1150972/making-traps-for-custom-oids-in-snmpd-conf) but still can't find a comprehensive answer about custom trap creation. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @user3159253 See the source code for this: http://snmppp.sourceforge.net/doc/doxygen/namespaceSNMPpp.html#a62783799405b5455e51082d0f5d6f8ab

Comment: Digging further, the actual source code with hopefully helpful comments to make the magic happen is in Trap.cpp.  See here:  https://sourceforge.net/p/snmppp/code/ci/master/tree/code/src/Trap.cpp